# How to link library manually?

Tags: react-native

I want to use `react-native-youtube` but it shows the error `Native component for "RCTYouTube" does not exist`, i try to find the solution it looks like i have to link the library manually if the library with native code.

But i have no idea with this link talk about `Manual linking Step1` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

I use type command `create-react-native-app testyoutube` to create my react native project, `Visual Studio Code` is my tool.

I'm not familiar with `Xcode`.  I try to open my project folder `testyoutube` in `Xcode`. It will show an alert `Could not open file.`

If i want to follow `Manual linking Step1` what step should i do ?

Here is my folder structure:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options to link libraries with your Xcode/Android project.

Automatic linking (run in your terminal in the root folder of your react-native project):

`react-native link`

Manual Setup:
It's actually very simple. Open your react native xcode project (.xcodeproject file) with Xcode.

On the left side you have the project navigator. Drag the Xcode project from react-native-youtube inside the Libraries group.

**Project Navigator**

[image]

Next step is to add the library to you project. Click on the left side on your xcode project in the project navigator. Go to the libraries section and add the RCTYoutube library.

After you have setup everything up, rebuild the project and you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PsykoSoldi3r , but i have no idea with `Open your react native xcode project (.xcodeproject file) with Xcode`. That means what folder or file should i open it in `Xcode` ? If i open my project folder `testyoutube` in `Xcode`, it can't be open.

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed on your machine? Xcode is only available on macOS https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: Yes, i use mac. I have to know i should open which folder, because i just open my react native project `testyoutube` in Xcode will show alert `Could not open file.`

Comment: Ah I see, you don't have any android and ios folder in your react-native project. By running the following command in your terminal: `react-native eject`, it will create a android project and ios project.

Before running that command, please read the instructions of create-native-react-app https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Comment: More information about react-native eject https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

Comment: Oh ! I get it now,  thanks for your help @PsykoSolidi3r, blessing.

Answer (score 7):

To expand upon [Adeel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5650328/adeel) answer:

1. Locate the RCTYouTube.xcodeproj at {your project root} /node_modules/react-native-youtube.
2. Use XCode to open your iOS project's .xcworkspace (or .xcodeproj if .xcworkspace does not exist).
3. Locate the 'Libraries' folder in the project navigator pane on the left hand side of the window and drag the RCTVideo.xcodeproj file inside it.
4. Select your project's target from the targets list pane on the inner left hand side of the window then scroll down to the 'Linked Libraries and Frameworks' section.
5. Click the plus symbol at the bottom of the section and use the search bar to find 'libRTCYouTube.a', select it from the results, and hit the 'Add' button.

Your library should now be linked!

Comment: It was so hard to follow the written description. It would have helped to add screenshots.